# Functional q-SQL: How to translate the fby part of the parse tree

Tags: kdb

When I run parse"select from trade where date=max date,price=(max;price) fby sym"

I get the following parse tree:

```
</br>

?

`trade

,((=;`date;(max;`date));(=;`price;(k){$[(#x 1)=#y;@[(#y)#x[0]0#x 1;g;:;x[0]'x..

0b

()
```

I tried interpreting this in functional form as:

```
?[trade;((=;`date;(max;`date));(=;`price;(k){$[(#x 1)=#y;@[(#y)#x[0]0#x 1;g;:;x[0]'x..;0b;()]
```

but I get an error pointing to the final. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You can replace the k code with fby, which will make it a lot neater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here. First is that your display window is not wide enough to show the full output. To adjust this window use [\c (console size)](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#c-console-size) command:

```
q)\c 25 200
q)parse"select from trade where date=max date,price=(max;price) fby sym"
?
`trade
,((=;`date;(max;`date));(=;`price;(k){$[(#x 1)=#y;@[(#y)#x[0]0#x 1;g;:;x[0]'x[1]g:.=y];'length]};(enlist;max;`price);`sym)))
0b
()
```

However, you will still have an issue using this because `parse` displays the full underlying k definition of `fby`:

```
q)fby
k){$[(#x 1)=#y;@[(#y)#x[0]0#x 1;g;:;x[0]'x[1]g:.=y];'length]}
```

Note that the definition is prefixed with "k)", which causes the error. To get around this you'll want to entirely replace the the k definition above with fby so that you have

```
?[trade;((=;`date;(max;`date));(=;`price;(fby;(enlist;max;`price);`sym)));0b;()]
```

rather than

```
?[trade;((=;`date;(max;`date));(=;`price;(k){$[(#x 1)=#y;@[(#y)#x[0]0#x 1;g;:;x[0]'x[1]g:.=y];'length]};(enlist;max;`price);`sym)));0b;()]
```

Comment: Thank-you for this detailed explanation. It has helped with my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fby rather than the k definition from parse:

`` ?[trade;(((=;`date;(max;`date));(=;`price;(fby;(enlist;max;`price);`sym))));0b;()!()] ``

Comment: Thank-you, that is so much nicer and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Aaron Davies in a KxCon talk a few years ago, you could use wrapper functions to make the code a bit easier to read:

```
q)trade:([]date:(.z.D-1),3#.z.D;sym:(3#`AA),`BB;price:1+til 4);
q)w:{(parse"select from t where ",x). 2 0}
q)?[trade;w"date=max date,price=(max;price)fby sym";0b;()]
date       sym price
--------------------
2020.09.24 AA  3
2020.09.24 BB  4
```

This "w" won't cover all possible use-cases but it can be expanded to cover the more general cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second parameter is getting cut off in your output. Notice how it ends with an ellipsis '..'. When you copy and paste it, you're only picking up part of the code.

,((=;date;(max;date));(=;`price;(k){$[(#x 1)=#y;@[(#y)#x[0]0#x 1;g;:;x[0]'x..  <- ellipsis here

Comment: Ah, thank-you so much. That has progressed me. For other Q-bies, like myself, you can set the length of the q consoles rows and columns by entering \c <number of rows> <number of columns>. For example \c 80 240.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to the above question, but I am sure some KDB developer will appreciate this at some point .

If you have a query like this :

```
select from x where i=fby[(last;i);([]col1;col2;col3; ...)]
```

And you want to pass the list of columns programatically.
This is what you are looking for

```
{[data;cls]
  ?[x;enlist (=;`i;(fby;(enlist;last;`i);(+:;(!;enlist cls;(enlist;enlist,cls)))));0b;()]     
  }[table;<your_list_of_cols_as_symbols>]
```